# Why are private members accessible from derived class (unsing member fxns of base class)

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my c++ program with `der` inheriting from `base`.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

class base
{
    int x;
public:
    int y;
    void set(int a,int b)
    {
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout<<"X ="<<x;
    }
};

class der:public base
{
    int i;
};

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int p,q;
    base o1;
    der o2;
    o2.y=10;
    o2.x=20;
    q=sizeof(o2);
    p=sizeof(o1);
    cout<<"Size of Abc "<<p;
    cout<<"\nSize of Der "<<q;

    getch();
}
```

Since we know that private members are not inherited but when I find the size of `o1` it gives 4 (obvious 2 int members) however size of `o2` is 6 but should have been 4 if `private` was not inherited. Can anyone help here please.

One more thing since I am able to public member fxns of base which in turn can access private data member so we can say private members become accessible outside class also

Comment: "Since we know that private members are not inherited" Your assumption is wrong. They are inherited just not directly accessible.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation and capitalisation so that it's legible.

Comment: Are you using Turbo C++? If so, stop. Seriously stop using it immediately. It's 20 years old. If your instructor/teacher/professor insists you use it go straight to the admissions office and demand a refund.

Comment: Well, it is part of syllabus, my teacher has no power to choose what to teach and what not. it depends on university

Comment: What university is this? I feel a strongly worded piece of nasty coming their way.

Comment: it is somewhere in north of India.

Comment: @user1387014 For some reason, many indian universities seem to be of the impression that it's a good idea to teach 20 years old - or older - technology in a field where the technological landscape has an extremely short lifespan. The C++ of the time of Turbo C++ has very little to do with what we have in 2013.

Answer (score 8):

> "sINCE WE KNOW THAT PRIVATE MEMBERS ARE NOT INHERITED"

That's not true at all.  Private members are inherited, but they are not accessible to the derived class.  So their storage is still present--otherwise the base class wouldn't have the ability to use its own members either (recall that a derived class object "is a" base class object, just with more stuff added).

Answer (score 0):

**ALL Non-static members are inherited to the derived class.**

**AND all members are accessible to derived class.**

`Public` and `Protected` members can be accessed `directly` and `Private` members can be 
accessed `indirectly` with the help of inherited member `functions` or through `pointer`.